# I have a walk cycle at place, how to make it move foward?

Tags: animation

How to do this?
If I move the root bone of my human rig, it will destroy all the poses of the walk cycle.

[image]

Comment: switch back to Object mode and move your armature, either with keyframes, or with a Follow Path consraint

Comment: Ok, in object mode, some bones on my rig's feet doesn't want to move along, when I tried to move everything. How to solve this?
I've already select all.

Comment: if those bones are part of the same armature, they will follow, so I'm not sure what's your problem, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok, the file is uploaded on the original post.

Comment: Your armature seems complicated, it has to do with the bone called b_L_Foot_ which has a Child Of constraint with CTRL_Target_L_Foot as Target, I don't know why it keeps it still though

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, align the b__L / R_Foot__ bone **orientation** and **roll** with CTRL_Target_L / R_Foot. 
Set **Copy Rotation** constraints to b__L/R_Foot__ bones instead of Child Of.

[image]

Comment: Mmm, I tested your suggestion, but the foot rig mechanism didn't work as intended. 
I think the reason because the local rotation transformation of the bone - roller_L_toe isn't registered if it's rotation is caused by child parent relationship.
So the bone - b_L_Foot doesn't have any data to copy/follow from.

Comment: I understand. I posted another method.

Comment: For further information: 
This rig is from sims4studio. The rig is for the use in the game SIMS 4. If I changed the alignment, it may work in blender, but it will be completely messed up in the SIMS4. The position/rotation of the origin of the bones is mandatory.

Comment: Another information:
After  a lot of testings, it seems that the behavior of the stucked/stilled foot happens when I insert a keyframe. So keyframe + 'child of' constraint (with only rotation) cause the problem in object mode. If no keyframe, no problem. If you happened to know about it, maybe you can share your experience. Because I've searched and searched for the answer. I can't find it. 
I tested this problem on blender 2.79 and 2.8. I don't know maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I made it!
I've found the work around.
By using a transformation constraint - rot - rot, on the b__L_foot targeting Roller_L_foot, in order for the Roller_L_foot functioning as a lever.

Then there's A work around for ctrl_l_foot bone that control the location and rotation of the all the foot bones and lever mechanism bones. It tooks me days to figure it out.

I add a new bone duplicating the exact rotation of b__L_foot, put it near the ctrl_L_foot. On the new bone I use child of constraint to the ctrl_L_foot, location and rotation.
And then I told the b__L_foot to copy rotation of that new bone.

Now I can start to learn animating for the walk cycle move foward. Geez... it's been 2-3 weeks. Learning from zero to create the foot mechanism and meet many problems.

I still can't find the answer of the original problem though. But I do know, child of - constraint with rotation only, cause a bone to stuck in the object mode when a keyframe is inserted.I tested in blender 2.79, 2.8 and 2.9. The same behavior. I think it's a bug.